# Add class to the tr alternate

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablerow

I am using grid control where the table has one tr is hidden which is open on click of the.. so I have tried below function to add class to odd row.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Activate TableStyling
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.management').each(function () {
        $(this).children('tbody').children(':odd').addClass('grey');
    });

});
```

But the problem is it counts that hidden TR too.. so I need the function which don't count that hidden TR & add the class alternatively to the viewed Tr's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
$(this).children('tbody').children(':visible:odd').addClass('grey');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K3vCD/

Comment: plz leave a comment after down voting!

Answer (score 5):

You could do:

```
$(this).children('tbody').children(':visible:odd').addClass('grey');
```

Also if your hidden `tr` has some special class or something, you can tho this:

```
$(this).children('tbody').children(':not(.<your hidden class>):odd')
    .addClass('grey');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try mixing the `:visible` pseudo-selector with the `:odd`.

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/SAdEE/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `:visible` selector.

```
$(this).children('tbody').children(':visible:odd').addClass('grey');
```

Answer (score 1):

Most, if not all the answers assume that your definition of "hidden" is the same as jQuerys. There are other cases where "hidden" may be something like height: 0px, obscure z-indexing with overlapping elements etc. In these very rare cases, the filter method could be used with your own logic to classify what is considered "hidden".

```
$(this).children('tbody').filter(function(){
   return this.isNotAHiddenTR(); // your custom logic.
   // return $(this).is(':visible'); // the most likely solution
}).children(':odd').addClass('grey');
```

Also, the `:visible` selector *will* return elements that have `visibility: hidden`.